# one #macro add a field and a case (in switch-case)

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, x-macros

How to define macro (`ALL_SWITCH`) to recognize another macro (`SINGLE_CASE`) occurrences as list, and insert codes into 2 different places?

Is it possible?

### Example

I want to create macro that have syntax roughly similar as :-

```
 SINGLE_CASE <Class Name> <Enum slot>  //add fields
 ALL_SWITCH              //recognize all calling SINGLE_CASE (see below)
```

Below is the expected usage.

**TopHeader.h**:-

```
 SINGLE_CASE Machine slot1
 SINGLE_CASE Machine slot2
 //^-------- will be replaced by below code (generate the whole class)
 template<class T> Sloter<Machine> : public GameObject {
     public: int slot1;  
     public: int slot2;          
 };

 SINGLE_CASE Turret slot3
 //^-------- will be replaced by below code 
 template<class T> Sloter<Turret>  : public GameObject {
     public: int slot3;            
 };
```

**Manager.h**:-

```
 class Manager{
     enum SlotX{ slot1,slot2,slot3 };
     public: int* provider(GameObject* gameObject, SlotX slotX){
         switch(slotX){
             ALL_SWITCH 
             //^---- will be replaced by below code (add only cases)
             case slot1:{ 
                 return &(static_cast<Machine*>(gameObject)->slot1); 
             }break;
             case slot2:{ 
                 return &(static_cast<Machine*>(gameObject)->slot2); 
             }break;
             case slot3:{ 
                 return &(static_cast< Turret*>(gameObject)->slot3); 
             }break;
         }
     }
 };
```

It is not a good design, but it is a simple example to consider whether `MACRO` can do something *aggregate*.

This feature is useful when I really want ultimate performance and flexibility,
e.g. [store index into member itself for extremely-fast hashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562943/datastructure-of-pointers-that-can-removet-addt-and-iterate-really-fast-h).

**I have read :-**

- [Creating a string list and an enum list from a C++ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530248/creating-a-string-list-and-an-enum-list-from-a-c-macro)
  It is too simple.
- [How can I generate a list via the C preprocessor (cpp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904255/how-can-i-generate-a-list-via-the-c-preprocessor-cpp)
  `SINGLE_CASE` (`FUNCTION_TABLE` in the solution) contains code, while mine does not.

I am not sure whether `x-macros` tag is appropriate.
(I have limited knowledge in this area.)

### My progress

```
#define SINGLE_CASE( ClassName, slotX) /
template<class T> Sloter<ClassName> : public GameObject { /
     public: int slotX;  /
};
```

I still don't know how to make it support many `slot` for the same class or code `ALL_SWITCH`.
I am considering defining some kinds of table in macro, then make other macro read it. (not possible?)

Comment: @rici Thank a lot rici!  I have never known that.

Comment: Instead of using the C++ preprocessor, you could write a simple preprocessor that replaces these self-defined "macros", and then run this program before compiling the code.

Comment: @Roland Illig   I have zero experience about this approach.   If it does not disturb you too much, may you share the workflow, please?  ... may be some links .... e.g. ....   Should I create a new project in Visual Studio, or write a custom script?  Which script language?  Should I use notepad++ or something?  ... some good practices ...   Thank!

Comment: @rici I think I can inject the definition .... http://ideone.com/oC62F1 (template class specialization define using macro)  .... and http://ideone.com/w2zCoN (add a field into a template class by macro).    .... or you mentioned a different thing?

Comment: @rici  Sorry for being not clear.  I edited the question by removing all "inject" words.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible. The preprocessor is not powerful enough. In general, avoid preprocessor. One of the stated design goals of C++ is eliminating the preprocessor.