# Make object keep pointer to other objects - but not add code to the object directly (decoupling)

Tags: c++, c++11, entity, components, maintainability

I have an entity-based-component system.

A `GameObject` (entity) keeps all pointers to all related `GameComponent`s.
All `GameComponent` keep a pointer to the `GameObject`.

If I know that I have to query one component from another component often (`Physics`<->`Graphics`), I will cache pointer of another component.

```
class Physics : public GameComponent {
    Graphics* graphic;  //different GameObject
};
class Graphics: public GameComponent {
    Physics * physic ;  //different GameObject
};
```

The cost of querying pointer from each other (`Physics->Graphics` and `Graphics->Physics`)   is very small.

### As time go by ...

Storing `Graphics`'s pointer in `Physics` and vice versa becomes less sensible and causes maintainability problem.

For example, if I want to add a new relation, e.g. `Physics-Player`, I will have to add a field into both classes :-

- add `Player*` to `class Physics`
- add `Physic*` to `class Player`

If I proceed, totally simple components will be clogged with many fields about **the relation** that hard to be tracked and maintained.

```
class Physic: public GameComponent {
    Graphic* graphicsMain;
    Graphic* graphicsSecondary;
    Player* playerPtr;
    Enemy* enemyPtr;
    //10+ as project grow
}
```

Code about query an object from another object are **scattering around in many places**.

**Question:** How to solve the maintainability issue without performance penalty?

### My workaround

I created a new `GameComponent` named `RelationNode`.
Then create a new system named `Relation` to manage every type of relation in **a single place**.
**Pros:** I can code all utility that I want, and it will work for every relation type.

```
class Physics : public GameComponent {
    //no keep Graphics pointer anymore ... clean :)
};
class Graphics: public GameComponent {
    //no keep  Physics pointer anymore ... clean :)
};
public RelationNode : public GameComponent {
    //... some code ... cache other component ...
    RelationNode* slot01; //shared Physics->Graphics and Graphics->Physics
    RelationNode* slot02; //Physic->graphicsSecondary
    .......
    RelationNode* slot20;
    //^ I can reuse same slot of variable if I am sure.
    //instead of "RelationNode*" , it can also be "GameObject*"
};
class Relation{ 
    Graphics* getGraphicsFromPhysics(Physics* gameComponent){
        RelationNode* a = toNode(gameComponent); //waste 1-2 indirection
        RelationNode* b = queryGraphicFromPhysics(gameComponent);
        Graphics* bCom= fromNode(b);             //waste 1-2 indirection
        return bCom;
    }
    //the real code is more elegant than this, but suffer the same issue
};
```

Now my code is so clean but suffer performance penalty from **indirection**.
It cost about 1-30% (profiled), depends on test case.

I have another [crazy idea about add field to component using macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383375/), but I don't like macro - it tends to cause other problems.

My old idea is to use `hashMap` e.g. `HashMap<Graphics*,Physics*>`, but it is much slower than my workaround (tested).

Comment: Not sure but this question might be *too broad*. You should look into **"Data Oriented Design"** and try to avoid all this pointer indirection by separating data from logic and thinking about component storage from a different perspective. I wrote [my Bachelor's thesis on ECSs](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305730566) - it might interest you.

Comment: Have you looked at the mediator pattern? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo Thank, .... it is very long.  Which pages?  Should I print all 150 pages?

Comment: @linuxfever  I have never dive into detail about it.   Thank.   Is it fast?  I believe it costs some indirection, same as mine.

Comment: @javaLover: why print...? The first part of the thesis covers general ECS design strategies, the second one covers my particular implementation.

Comment: @javaLover yes, there is indirection which is exactly what breaks the coupling. In terms of speed, you will have to test it I am afraid... good luck!

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo  My bad ... the document is already well bookmarked.    I found a few parts that has potential ....  **1. Address-based**   same as I am using (very coupling).  **2. Subscription-based** and **Message-based** : not related to me.  **3.Inter-entity** = entity call another entity's function, not related to me.  ....  I don't find any part address the issue about how to design database/system to manage relation between entity.   I guess it is ECS's limitation. (?)

Comment: You can manage relationships between entities by having "glue" components that store the ids of the connected entities. Then you can have a system that processes those "glue" components and gets the entities to perform logic on all of them at the same time

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo `RelationNode` is a glue, isn't it?  (sorry if my code is not clear)  It costs some indirection, though.  Is there any glue technique that has CPU cost same as the shiny **Address-based** way?